# Is there away to schedule a report which contains all the email sends and it has be sent to a particular email ids on weekly basis in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, custom-report-type, custom-reports, automated-process

I need help to create report for all the journeys which we have triggered and this report has to be mailed to a particular set of email ids automatically on weekly basis. Is there a way.. pls guide.

**How I used to do till now:**

I used to manually generate "Journey Builder Email Send Summary" report under Analytics Builder -> Report and take data from this report and put it in excel in an easily readable format and send this.

Can this be automated to get all the email sends report and send.

Please assist.

Comment: The UI is terribly unintuitive, but first save the summary report then click on the schedule button once saved. You can enter multiple recipient email addresses separated by a semicolon: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_re_faq4.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks Macca.. but i need a custom report with the following columns:CampaignName
Type
Subscribers Targeted 
Sent 
Delivered 
Open 
Unique Open 
% Unique Open 
Total Click 
Unique Click 
%Click

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can achieve if you have Intelligence Reports for Engagement (formerly Marketing Cloud Datorama Reports).

> Intelligence Reports for Engagement—This standard version is included
> in Pro editions and higher.

Go to Analytics Builder > Intelligence Reports > Reports tab > Create report.

Select the columns needed. Here is an example based on your comment:

[image]

**For information:**

> There are two types of data elements available: dimensions and
> measurements.
>
> **Dimensions:** Qualitative, non-numerical data (data you can’t count)
> like, campaign name, campaign ID, and so on.
>
> **Measurements:** Quantitative, numerical data (data you can count) like, number of
> clicks, emails opened, and so on.

Once done with this part, you can move on to the scheduling. You can mail this report to a list of emails on a weekly basis.

[image]

You can play with many parameters as you can see in the images, like choosing the Time period, selecting which day of the week to mail the report as well as the delivery hour,...

**Resources:**

- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_dat_datorama_reports.htm&type=5
- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/datorama-reports-for-marketing-cloud/get-to-know-datorama-reports-for-marketing-cloud?trail_id=measure-your-marketing-impact

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information Rachid. But i think  Intelligence Reports are not enabled for my account. i couldnt see any.